# from types to write a function that satisfies the types

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, ml

This question is taken from an exam. I don't know how to do that. :-(

Question: Give an example of a haskell or ml function whose type is

**( a -> b ) -> ( c -> a ) -> c -> b**

How to do that?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/ in future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What meaningful function could have the type `mystery :: ( a -> b ) -> ( c -> a ) -> c -> b`?

Let's see, what could

```
mystery f g x
```

be?

It has three things to work with,

- one value `x` of type `c`,
- one function `g` of type `c -> a` and
- one function `f` of type `a -> b`.

It shall produce a value of type `b`.

The only argument that has anything to do with `b` is the function `f`, so the result must be `f ???`.

What can be the argument of `f` here? It must have type `a`, and the only way to produce a value of that type from the given arguments (ignoring bottoms, `undefined`, `error "foo"`) is applying `g` to something, so it must be

```
mystery f g x = f (g ??)
```

But what could `g` be applied to? That must be a value of type `c`. Apart from bottoms, the only value of type `c` that can be constructed from the arguments is `x`, so

```
mystery f g x = f (g x)
```

*must* be function composition (or undefined).

Comment: This is also explained rather nicely here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Function_composition

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's the answer what I want! Daniel, Really thanks. :-)

Comment: What if my type is like this, (a->a->a)->a->a? @Daniel

Comment: @henry Try the method Daniel suggested yourself. Where do you get stuck? (If you don't get stuck... well, then you have the answer! =)

Comment: Very good explanation! Though, for me, a bit surprising as it goes top down when my initial thoughts were, to the contrary, bootom up. e.g. there is only one thing we can do with x, namely, apply g to it, which yields an a, that could only be used as argument for f, and we have the final b. -- Interesting question: are both methods equivalent in the sense that we get a  solution with "top down" if and only if we get also one with "bottom up"?

Comment: @Ingo My first version was bottom-up. I think, however, that top-down is easier to see (here, at least). Bottom-up, if you have the patience (or the data are nice enough), you build the complete graph of paths from the starting point (unless you have cycles, then the graph can never be complete), top-down, you build the complete (same reservation) graph of paths ending at the target. So both ways find all possible paths from the origin to the target (again, if there are no cycles).

Answer (score 4):

The other answers so far don't actually show the logical procedure for doing this in general.  I won't show it in 100% detail either, but I'll give an example of it.

The "deep" trick to this is that finding a function of a given type is equivalent proving a a logical theorem.  Using a form of [Lemmon's System L](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_L_%28Lemmon%29) (a friendlier form of [natural deduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction) used in some beginning logic courses), your example would go like this:

```
Theorem:  ??? :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b

1.                 f :: a -> b  (aux. assumption)
2.                 g :: c -> a  (aux. assumption)
3.                 x :: c       (aux. assumption)
4.               g x :: a       (2, 3, -> elim; assumes 2, 3)
5.           f (g x) :: b       (1, 4, -> elim; assumes 1, 2, 3)
6.     \x -> f (g x) :: c -> b  (3, 4, -> intro; discharges 3, assumes 1, 2)

7.   \g x -> f (g x) :: (c -> a) -> c -> b
                        (2, 6, -> intro; discharges 2, assumes 1)

8. \f g x -> f (g x) :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b  
                        (1, 7, -> intro; discharges 1)
```

The idea here is that [there is a tight correspondence between functional programming languages and logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry-Howard_correspondence), such that:

1. Types correspond to logical propositions
2. Function definitions correspond to logical proofs
3. Logical proof rules correspond to rules on how to construct programming language expressions.

So the "auxiliary assumption" logical proof rule (steps 1-3) corresponds to introducing a fresh free variable.  The implication elimination rule (steps 4-5, a.k.a. "modus ponens") corresponds to function application.  The implication introduction rule (steps 6-8, a.k.a. "hypothetical reasoning") corresponds to lambda abstraction.  The concept of discharging auxiliary assumptions corresponds to binding free variables.  The concept of a proof with no premises corresponds to the concept of an expression with no free variables.

Answer (score 2):

That function is the function composition operator, and by typing the function's type into Hoogle you could find that out: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28+a+-%3E+b+%29+-%3E+%28+c+-%3E+a+%29+-%3E+c+-%3E+b++

You can then click to show the source:

```
(.)    :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(.) f g = \x -> f (g x)
```